# Xcode target architecture

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, architecture, ios

I have an iPhone app that I am trying to port to MacOS.  To get things started, I added a MacOS target to my existing Xcode project.

The problem I am having is that when I switch from the MacOS target to the iOS target, it tries to build it with architecture i386, which leads to like a zillion compiler errors.

In my target settings for the iOS target, it shows valid architectures as armv6 and armv7.

Here is the first error:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:24: error: i386/types.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in XCode, which is circumvented by option-clicking (i.e. alt-clicking) on the overview, usually top-left in the xcode window, and then selecting the right SDK. The architecture then changes to the right one (hopefully).

Comment: This didn't fix it for me and I have the same problem.